# Django ORM aggregate over related array field

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm, django-postgresql

I have two models

```py
class Record(Model):
    scorable_entry = models.ForeignKey('Entry',
                                       null=True,
                                       blank=True,
                                       on_delete=models.CASCADE)

class Entry(Model):
    scores = ArrayField(models.IntegerField(), null=True)
```

and I need to sort `Records` based on the sum of `scores` on a related `Entry` model.

Unfortunately, this naive code throws an error

```py
records
.annotate(score_rows=Func(F('scorable_entry__scores'), function='unnest'))
.annotate(scores_sum=sum('score_rows'))
.order_by('-scores_sum')
```

```
django.db.utils.NotSupportedError: aggregate function calls cannot contain set-returning function calls
```

I'm using [unnest](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-array.html) to convert array to rows first (because otherwise `sum` wouldn't work).
Skipping unnesting doesn't work as sum doesn't operate on arrays

```
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: function sum(integer[]) does not exist
HINT:  No function matches the given name and argument types. You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

What is the proper way to order elements by the sum of a related array using ORM?

Django `3.1`, Postgres `12.9`

Comment: Have you tried: `from django.db.models import Sum` and `Record.objects.annotate(total_entries=Sum('scorable_entry__scores')).order_by('-total_entries')`

Comment: @Ahtisham yes, in this case second error pops up like described above

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create postgres function to sum up `int[]` and use it in annotation

```
create or replace function int_array_sum(arr int[])
returns int
language plpgsql
as
$$
declare
    result integer;
begin
   select sum(a) into result
   from unnest(arr) a;

    return result;
end;
$$;
```

Here the query

```
Record.objects
    .annotate(scores_sum=Func(F('scorable_entry__scores'), function='int_array_sum'))
    .order_by('-scores_sum')
```

Answer (score 0):

So I've ended up using migration including the custom function from Yevhen's answer

```py
ARRAY_SUM_FUNCTION = """
create or replace function int_array_sum(arr integer[])
returns int
language plpgsql
as
$$
declare
    result integer;
begin
    select sum(a) into result
    from unnest(arr) a;
    return result;
end;
$$;
"""
```

Note `arr integer[]` parameter type.

```py
from django.db import migrations


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('records', '0003_auto_20151206_1219'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.RunSQL(ARRAY_SUM_FUNCTION)
    ]
```